# What is mean by VREF Training in DDR4?

Tags: signal-integrity, ddr, ddr3, ddr4

While going through DDR3 and DDR4, there is a term called vref. Where in DDR3 it is outside the DDR and for DDR4 it is inside the chip. Why we need training for it. What is the use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$V_{ref}\$ is the comparison voltage to determine whether a data line is at high or low state.

For DDR3, this is half of the supply voltage for the drivers that drive these lines (so the I/O supply), this can be generated easily with a resistor divider, and reused after buffering as the termination supply for the A/C lines.

For DDR4, the lines are driven asymmetrically, so the center of the data eye is not at half voltage, and in fact slightly different for each IC, so RAM ICs generate their own reference voltage, for this to work a specific training sequence is sent by the memory controller, and the IC determines the optimum reference voltage. This might need to be repeated later as voltages shift due to temperature changes.

Comment: Thanks, but why we go to this feature called vref to check the received voltage is high or low, we can simply confirm it high or low based on DC threshold values like other signals.

Comment: @Selva97, input buffers pretty much always compare against a reference voltage, but many ICs generate this internally with a simple resistor divider, as it doesn't need to be particularly precise.

Comment: Thanks simon, i got some idea now. Will this vref is constant for all the signals in ddr or each ddr signal can have its own vref for better efficiency.

Comment: @Selva97, for DDR3: each IC has two Vref inputs, one for the Address/Control bus, one for the Data lines. Typical setups will use the same voltage here, but for some power saving modes you might want them separate. For DDR4: it's undefined, the individual ICs generate that internally.

Comment: Thanks Simon, get overall idea about VREF. Could you please share any useful documents about ddr.

Answer (score 1):

This bugged me for a long time when I was learning about DDR interface. So let me try to explain. First you need to know little bit about SSTL and POD interface, since that helps to explain why we need internal Vref and training on DDR4 onwards. Following image shows SSTL and POD interface. SSTL is used on DDR3 and POD is used on DDR4 and DDR5. without confusing you a lot, here is what all you need to know:

1. On SSTL interface, you have a symmetric swing of the signal, so if you want to know whether signal is 0 or 1, you need to use Vref equal to VDDQ/2 i.e. middle of the swing.
2. On POD interface, this is different because you have an asymmetric swing. In this case the signal is more towards VDDQ. So in this case Vref is closer to 0.75*VDDQ. But actual value of the Vref will depend on the resistor (ODT) and also the drive strength of driver. So we need a way to generate Vref internally rather than having a fixed Vref (like we had on DDR3) and we also need to train and find the optimal value of Vref which gives us maximum margin.

Again this is very high level explanation and hopefully it helps.

[image: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02381-6_2]